# Comparing two columns in Excel VBA (greater/less than or equal to)

Tags: excel, function, vba, compare

I'm actually quite surprised that I'm having so much trouble finding as answer for this. I have 2 columns containing a bunch of numbers (on the same worksheet). I simply want to have code to say "If the value in column 1 > the value in column 2, do this" for each row in the columns. I tried

```
If sheet.range("B2:B35").Value > sheet.range("C2:C35").Value Then
'do something
End If
```

But apparently it doesn't work that way.

Comment: I believe you will need to check each pair of elements in turn .. but I don't touch Excel, much less VBA :)

Comment: yes, because there isn't a single value representing everything in rows 2 - 35

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to think about a loop to check each row independently of the others.

The idea is something like:

```
For i = 2 to 35
    If Sheet.Range("B" & i).Value > Sheet.Range("C" & i).Value
        'Do Something for Row i
    End If
Next
```

The `Value` can be omitted as it is implicit, meaning `Sheet.Range("B" & i).Value` returns an identical result as `Sheet.Range("B" & i)`

Additionally, there are numerous ways to address a cell depending on your needs.

```
  Range() 'Can be used to address multiple cells at the same time over a range
          ' or used to address a single cell as is done here

  Cells() 'Can be used to address a single Cell by calling Cells("B" & i) as is 
          ' done above, or can reference the row and column numerically like  
          ' Cells(2, i)
```

And either of the above methods can be used in conjunction with `Offset()` if you are looking to move around a given worksheet such as:

```
  Cells(2, 1).Offset(0, i) 'Addresses the Cell offset from "B1" by 0 columns and
                           ' i rows.
```

I personally tend to use `Cells(2, i)` in these cases, but I just used `Range` as I borrowed it straight from your example code snippet.

Comment: And indeed it was that simple. Sigh. Thank you.

Comment: You can also use `Sheet.Cells(i,2).Value` and `Sheet.Cells(i,3)` if this is more clear

Comment: +1 but would be better to have `.Value` explicit on both sides of `>` or implicit on both sides. Currently have it explicit on LHS and implicit on RHS

Comment: @barrowc that was a typo, I just missed the 2nd `Value` when typing.  Fixed.  Thank you for pointing it out.