# Excel: "countif" or "if count"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to compare two rows: C17:X17 with C10:X10

If C17:Z17>C10:Z10, then count the number of instances.

I've tried
`=IF(C17:X17>C10:X10,COUNT(C17:X17),0)`
and I've also tried
`=COUNTIF(C17:X17,C17:X17>C10:X10)`

Any help? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Try using VisualBasic's scripting engine

Comment: Thanks, @isaiah. I'm new to Excel and have heard about VBA and macros. I'm not sure how or when to implement them, and I was hoping this computation could be performed w/o these tools.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just make another row which compares the two and sum it?  e.g., C18: if(C17>C10,1,0) then copy across all relevant columns and have another cell be =sum(C18:Z18)?

Comment: @isaiah, thanks, but that is not very helpful.

Comment: @mark, Thanks for the input. I think that could work, but creating a new row would be very time consuming (I would have to do it for each of the 365 rows, as opposed to a formula that does not require that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using SUMPRODUCT like this:

> =SUMPRODUCT((C17:Z17>C$10:Z$10)+0)

I made the row 10 reference absolute - then you can copy down and that part won't change

Comment: Barry! Thank you for the answer, and also for adding the "$" for me. Rockstar.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you want to compare two 'vectors' and you can't make a new 'vector' with a formula, you might want to consider VBA as an option.

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12700202/2890590) as a starting point we can see some VBA for looping of rows:

```
Dim x As Integer
x=0
For i = 3 to 26
    If Sheet.Cells(i, 17).Value > Sheet.Cells(i,10).Value
        x=x+1
    End If
Next
Sheet.Range("D1").Value = x
```

Here, all you need to do is change the cell referenced on the last line to where you want the count to go.